# Do you get a notification if your comment is deleted?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, deleted-comments

Basically the title is the question: Do you get a notification if your comment is deleted?

I couldn't find the answer in the help center or here on meta. But I'm pretty sure that I had comments under several questions/answers which aren't there anymore, so do you get a notification or do your comments simply vanish into oblivion?

Comment: No you don't get a notification, they are just gone.

Comment: It's not listed in the linked FAQ, so you don't get a notification.

Comment: @Glorfindel now it is, I've added it under "Notable events which do not trigger an inbox notification". :)